# Which SOLID and modern OO principles will be affected, and how, if we remove adherence to separation of concerns?

Tags: oop, solid-principles, separation-of-concerns

Say I break the principle of Separation of Concerns (SoC) and deliberately write, plan, and design my code to break, avoid and go against the SoC principle.

What other OO and SOLID principles will necessarily be affected, and how?  Is some SoC necessary for code to work, or can it be completely avoided?

Comment: Such questions about software architecture and design principles may be better suited at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

S and O will be mostly affected, but you could still preserve L, I and D if you were disciplined. You can write bad code without following any design best practices and still get it to work. I see the data scientists at my company do this every day!